# Why can't we view Google Drive public file for longer without getting 403 Forbidden Error?

Tags: python-3.x, django, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, http-status-code-403

I am working on a Django project where I allow user to upload their images on google drive with public access and then I display all the uploaded images user-wise.

Everything done, I can create folder, and then uploading file in it and getting the file-id. But on viewing that image, I have stucked badly.

I have used so many ways not to get a 403 Forbidden Error but still no success!

[https://drive.google.com/file/d/{file-id}/preview](https://drive.google.com/file/d/%7Bfile-id%7D/preview)

[https://drive.google.com/uc?id={file-id}&export=download](https://drive.google.com/uc?id=%7Bfile-id%7D&export=download)

[https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id={file-id}](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=%7Bfile-id%7D)

File (which is just an image) I can view only few times but then I starts getting this annoying 403 forbidden error.

I am really frustrated with this error, please help.

Here is my full code from utils.py file

```
from __future__ import print_function
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload, MediaIoBaseDownload
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google.auth.exceptions import RefreshError
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import redirect
import argparse
import base64
import json
import io, os
import shutil
import requests
from pebble import concurrent

TOKEN_DIR = "oauth_tokens/drive"

class Drive:
    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file']

    extensions = {"csv": "text/csv", "mpeg": "video/mpeg", "mpg": "video/mpeg", "tiff": "image/tiff",
                  "wmv": "video/x-ms-wmv", "xlsx": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
                  "zip": "application/x-zip-compressed"}

    def __init__(self,email):
        self.email = email
        self.creds = self.load_credentials()
        if self.creds is not None:
            self.service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=self.creds)
        else:
            self.service = None

    def generate_authorization_url(self):
        print("inside generate_authorization_url")
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            settings.GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRETS_JSON, self.SCOPES, redirect_uri="http://localhost:8000/google_drive_callback/"
        )
        print("flow in generate_authorization_url", flow)
        # Generate the authorization URL
        authorization_url, _ = flow.authorization_url(
            access_type='offline',
            include_granted_scopes='false'
        )
        print("authorization_url in generate_authorization_url ",authorization_url)
        return authorization_url

    def fetch_credentials(self, authorization_code):
        print("inside fetch_credentials")
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            settings.GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRETS_JSON, self.SCOPES, redirect_uri="http://localhost:8000/google_drive_callback/"
        )
        # Exchange the authorization code for credentials
        creds = flow.fetch_token(code=authorization_code)
        print("creds in fetch_credentials",creds)
        # Serialize the credentials to JSON and save them to a file
        creds_json = {
            "token": creds['access_token'],
            "refresh_token": creds.get('refresh_token',"1//0gTWnxxxxRAAGBASNwF-xxxxxxx-JFK_Yg"), 
            "scopes": creds['scope'],
            "expires_at":creds['expires_at'],
            "token_type":creds['token_type'],
            "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
            "client_id": "175xxxxn.apps.googleusercontent.com", 
            "client_secret": "GOCSPX-XXXXXX"
        }
        print("creds_json in fetch_credentials",creds_json)
        token_path = os.path.join(TOKEN_DIR, f"{self.email}_token.json")
        try:
            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(token_path), exist_ok=True)
            with open(token_path, 'w') as token_file:
                json.dump(creds_json, token_file)
                print("token.json updated.")
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error writing credentials to token.json:", str(e))

        return creds

    def load_credentials(self):
        token_path = os.path.join(TOKEN_DIR, f"{self.email}_token.json")
        if not os.path.exists(token_path):
            print("file not found in load_credentials")
            creds_json = {"token": "ya29.a0AfB_byD7t9wWRGsuERfEt3xxxxxS92ZW_MDFcPcuuKrT8IoRfcFWinRZ-xSYxxYXwjtnCJlvxxxxnSOS2xBtXm7F05eagPHyg6F9xUD7rmz_uZzAqv5EugxQKaCgYKAYgSARISFQGOcNnCv4v3mTcbXRtdT0T4ZPtQpQ0171", "refresh_token": "1//0gOgL_UZ_xxxxx-L9Ir0W_-0kLqhgtnosiiWBESLDUQwP21VIl1j6Q_sPrO34tl-wZzJfXK4RJl0-PAmxCQ9ws", "scopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"], "expires_at": 1696676452.3799534, "token_type": "Bearer", "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token", "client_id": "175XXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com", "client_secret": "GOCSPX-XXXXXX"}
            try:
                with open(token_path, 'w') as token_file:
                    json.dump(creds_json, token_file)
                    print("token.json created in load_credentials.")
            except Exception as e:
                print("Error writing credentials to token.json:", str(e))
        if os.path.exists(token_path):
            print("token_path found in load_credentials")
            creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file(token_path, scopes=self.SCOPES)
            # Check if the credentials need refreshing
            if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
                try:
                    creds.refresh(Request())
                    print("creds.refresh(Request()) completed")
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Error refreshing token in load_credentials: {str(e)}")

                    return None

            return creds

        return None


    def shareWithEveryone(self, folderId, payload):
        payload = {
            "role": "reader",
            "type": "anyone"
        }
        return self.service.permissions().create(fileId=folderId, body=payload).execute()

    def create_folder(self, folder_name):
        try:
            folder_id = None
            query = "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false and name='" + folder_name + "'"
            results = self.service.files().list(
                pageSize=1, q=query, fields="files(id, name)").execute()
            folders = results.get('files', [])

            if folders:
                folder_id = folders[0]['id']
            else:
                file_metadata = {
                    'name': folder_name,
                    'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
                }
                folder_file = self.service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                                          fields='id').execute()

                folder_id = folder_file.get('id')

            return folder_id
        except RefreshError as e:
            # Handle RefreshError by reauthorizing
            self.creds = self.load_credentials()
            if self.creds is not None:
                self.service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=self.creds)
                # You can log the error, retry the operation, or take other actions as needed
        except Exception as e:
            # Handle other exceptions as appropriate
            print(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")

    def upload_file(self, folder_id, file_name):
        try:
            file_metadata = {
                'name': file_name.temporary_file_path(),
                'parents': [folder_id]
            }

            media = MediaFileUpload(file_name.temporary_file_path(),
                                    mimetype=self.extensions[file_name.name.split(".")[1]], resumable=True)
            _file = self.service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                                media_body=media, fields='id').execute()

            aas = Drive(email=self.email).shareWithEveryone(folder_id, file_metadata)

            file_id = _file.get('id')

            return file_id
        except RefreshError as e:
            # Handle RefreshError by reauthorizing
            self.creds = self.load_credentials()
            if self.creds is not None:
                self.service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=self.creds)
                # You can log the error, retry the operation, or take other actions as needed
        except Exception as e:
            # Handle other exceptions as appropriate
            print(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")


    def logout(self):
        # Revoke Google token (use the user's refresh token)
        if self.creds and self.creds.refresh_token:
            try:
                token_info_url = 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/revoke'
                payload = {
                    'token': self.creds.refresh_token
                }
                response = requests.post(token_info_url, data=payload)
                if response.status_code == 200:
                    print("Token Drive revoked successfully")
                else:
                    print("Failed to revoke token:", response.status_code)
            except Exception as e:
                print("Error while revoking token:", str(e))
```

I call this functions as like

```
drive = Drive(email=request.user)
file-id= drive.upload_file(folder_id,filename)
```

and this is how i get the file-id which I used with the above mentioned URLs to view in webpage.

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo I have updated my question by providing the full code. Please help :(

Comment: Where exactly does the error occur? Does your django view display a 403 error, or is it the `drive.upload_file(folder_id, filename)` that ends up in `except Exception as e: print...` ? It would be great to see the full error and possibly its backtrace.

Comment: @Tarquinius No, Django View doesn't display a 403 Error. But in the webpage, Image doesn't load and in the inspect element of browser (console) I can see this 

`GET https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1J6XXXXJpBoxy9&export=download 403 (Forbidden)`

Comment: Have you considered using Google Cloud Storage?

Answer (score 1):

I documented the workaround to [embed Google Drive images in your website](https://justin.poehnelt.com/posts/google-drive-embed-images-403/). There is also an open bug that corresponds to the timeline of the error your are experiencing: https://issuetracker.google.com/319531488

> For other files, once opened in Drive, select “Open in new window” from the overflow menu, and then open the overflow menu and select “Embed item…”, which provides the iframe HTML tag.

Use this HTML iframe instead.

```html
<iframe 
  src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/YOUR_FILE_ID/preview" 
  width="640" height="480" allow="autoplay"
></iframe>
```

But there are [limitations](https://justin.poehnelt.com/posts/google-drive-embed-images-403/#limitations).

Comment: iframe solution is not acceptable, i am going to host images elsewhere unless a solution is found.my few images on google sites stopped working yesterday, and their native "insert image" option is no good.

Comment: See question and answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77803187/having-trouble-displaying-an-image-from-google-drive-in-html-using-javascript/77805668#77805668

Answer (score 0):

I have also hit this issue and it's quite frustrating. I found a PARTIAL workaround, so I'm posting it here in the hopes that somebody can run with it for a better solution:

Insert the image ID in this format: https://lh3.google.com/u/0/d/(File ID)

The image will display if you are logged into ANY Google account. You can attempt it in a private window or without being logged into a Google account and the image is broken.

Answer (score 0):

alternative solution for a while

```
<img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=xxxxxxx&sz=w1000">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use iframes. Start by opening the desired file in Google Drive, selecting "Open in new window" from the overflow menu, and then choosing "Embed item." This action generates an iframe HTML tag, which can be added to a website for embedding the image.

You can read an article on this issue [here](https://adityadhandi.medium.com/how-to-embed-images-from-google-drive-on-your-website-c12a329c8cb0):