# Having trouble displaying an image from Google Drive

Tags: javascript, html, image

I'm struggling to show an image from Google Drive on my HTML page using JavaScript. Following online guides hasn't quite solved it for me.

**HTML (index.html):**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Google Drive Image</title>
</head>
<body>
  <img id="imageElement" alt="A lovely image">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript (script.js):**

```js
const fileId = '1BEW9tkgVKlp_ebUc17LkXDH-mnPc4ome';
const imageElement = document.getElementById('imageElement');

async function fetchGoogleDriveImage(fileId) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`https://drive.google.com/uc?id=${fileId}`);
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(await response.blob());
    imageElement.src = url;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching the image:', error);
  }
}

fetchGoogleDriveImage(fileId);
```

**Context:**

- Image in Google Drive is set to "Anyone with the link can view."
- Despite that, the image doesn't load in the browser, and the console shows an error.

**Additional HTML (with pure html):**

```html
<body>
  <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1BEW9tkgVKlp_ebUc17LkXDH-mnPc4ome" alt="Your Image Alt Text">
</body>
```

**[CodePen Example](https://codepen.io/raulpenate/pen/NWJRmaN)**

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: If you already have a web host, to hold the HTML, then why don't you copy the images to the web host?

Comment: The codepen is getting `403 Forbidden` when it tries to fetch from Google Drive.

Comment: Anybody *with* the link can view it, not anybody who embeds the link. Since this violates their CORs policy, you get the 403. Test: navigate directly to the image url from the browser; the skull image shows

Comment: Google Drive is not a hosting service; they do not allow embedding of content like that. There's a dupe somewhere...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I display images from Google Drive on a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15557392/how-do-i-display-images-from-google-drive-on-a-website)

Comment: @GetSet maybe it does violate their policy but it doesn't seem clearly defined. This seems to have worked up until a few hours ago today so they must have changed something. Google Drive has quotas so I don't see why they would care HOW those quotas get utilized, embedding or otherwise.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Though not published anywhere (that I've found), Google Drive's servers have begun rejecting requests where these two headers are attached:

```
sec-fetch-mode: no-cors
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
```

If you navigate your browser *directly* to the (direct link) URL of the file, (i.e. take your `src` URL and just paste it into the browser nav bar), the `sec-fetch-mode` header during that request will be set to `navigate` and it works just fine.

But, as with your `<img>` example, if the source of the request is a web page, and which is not the same origin as `drive.google.com`, hence the problem. (Your browser will automatically set those `sec-fetch-mode` and `sec-fetch-site` headers as part of the request.)

This appears to be an undocumented change by Google Drive that started on January 10, 2024 and I still can't find any mention of it anywhere, so it's unknown if this behavior will persist or if it reflects an accidental change or oversight.

Comment: I found this google bug issue tracker dedicated to this (new) problem - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/319531488?pli=1

Comment: Thanks, I allowed origin `https://drive.google.com` in my backend CORS configuration and started to work

Answer (score 9):

I have the same problem. A temporary solution is to use a drive file thumbnail with a large width.

```
<img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=xxxxxxxx&sz=w1000">
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working! https://codepen.io/raulpenate/pen/wvOozzw

Comment: Nice workaround. but it doesn't seem to be a guaranteed long term fix, Google might start rejecting this as well.

Answer (score 7):

The temporary solution for this would be to replace the Google Drive URLs to a different format that forces the image to be downloaded and displayed. This can be achieved by replacing `uc?id=` with `thumbnail?id=` and appending `&sz=w1000` at the end of the URL. The `sz=w1000` parameter specifies the width of the image. You can adjust this value according to your needs.
The final URL format should look like this:

```
https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=FILE_ID&sz=w1000
```

```
eg: 
<body>
   <img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1BEW9tkgVKlp_ebUc17LkXDH-mnPc4ome&sz=w1000" alt="Your Image Alt Text">
</body>
```

- Old URL: `https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1BEW9tkgVKlp_ebUc17LkXDH-mnPc4ome`
- New URL: `https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1BEW9tkgVKlp_ebUc17LkXDH-mnPc4ome&sz=w1000`

You can also use VSCode or any other text editor that has a Regex search to search and replace URL if you have it in bulk:
Eg:

Search:

```
https:\/\/drive\.google\.com\/uc\?id=([^"]+)
```

Replace:

```
https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=$1&sz=w1000
```

Using this Regex you search and replace all the URLs in your codebase.

---

*Please do note that this is a temporary solution and Google might stop the support for thumbnails in the future.*

Answer (score 4):

You're doing everything right here, it seems the issue is on Google's end and started happening today (January 11, 2024 at time of writing). Google might fix this issue and allow direct image embedding, or they might continue to block it, meaning you'll have to find an alternative way of hosting images for websites, such as S3.

(Possible) Bug being tracked here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/319531488?pli=1

Answer (score 3):

I was struggling with same problem and found an earlier answer which was to use this form of the url:

```
https://lh3.google.com/u/0/d/<file-id>
```

It worked, but I'll keep my eye on it to check that it continues working.

Answer (score 1):

***Official Google dev team final decision:***

**Source:** [Google Issue Tracker - Comment #175](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/319531488#comment175)

> **Status:** Won't Fix (Intended Behavior)
>
> Closing this issue as working as intended. I tried to buy some more time with the team owning this to no avail. Some points:
>
> - Related to phase out of third party cookies. [October 2023 Blog Post](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2023/10/upcoming-changes-to-third-party-cookies-in-google-drive.htm)
> - This was never an officially supported usage. (Same for `lh3.google.com`, thumbnail links mentioned above, etc)
>
> **Options going forward:**
>
> 1. Use the embed pattern described in the above blog post or [here](https://justin.poehnelt.com/posts/google-drive-embed-images-403)
> 2. Move files to a location designed for hosting, e.g., Google Cloud Storage or any number of hosting providers for static content
> 3. Proxy the files through the Google Drive API using your own infrastructure, e.g., Google Cloud Functions. Watch out for egress costs and hot linking; probably want a CDN too
> 4. Use a hosted proxy service as mentioned above