# Audio stopped playing after working several thousand times on line

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

The audio file, a 14 second mp3, is still at the google public drive as I can play the audio directly from the drive using the reference address from google chrome.

In my javascript, I define the audio source as shown:

```html
<audio id="AveClip" preload>
    <source src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1mCd9HuDu2TqwRnlwe7LB4PbZkcJYdXLC" />
</audio>
```

and the web page provides a button to play the audio:

```html
<button style="font-size: 1.2em" onclick="document.getElementById('AveClip').play();">Ave:</button>
```

When the button is pressed no audio is played.

The code has executed over 4000 times (web site accesses) without error and without changing the code it simply stopped playing at all when the button is pressed.  I put in an alert both before and after the `document.getElementById('AveClip').play();` on the button definition shown above and the alerts display so I know the code to access the the audio file within the program are getting executed but there is no audio.  Hence I suspect the the preload is not happening.  Is there a way to find out what is happening?

Comment: Likely related, a SO post and discussion regarding newly instituted **google drive CORS policy** ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77803187/having-trouble-displaying-an-image-from-google-drive-in-html-using-javascript#comment137160872_77803187

Comment: Right.  Put simply, Google never intended for Google Drive to be a content delivery service for web sites, and they are now enforcing this.