# Using HTML <audio> tag with google drive gives 403 Forbidden

Tags: html, google-drive-api, html5-audio

Using the HTML  tag with Google Drive gives

`403 Forbidden`

```
 <audio controls="controls">
        <source src="https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=<ABCD>">
 </audio>
```

When executing the above code snipped, the error is thrown as
`403 Forbidden`

This was working all these years as I was using them on my website but suddenly noticed that none of the audio files on the website seemed to work because of this error.

Comment: The issue is likely to be because browsers (and websites themselves) are blocking or disabling third-party cookies for security and privacy reasons.

Comment: Not sure why this is happening suddenly !!!  Is there a solution for rectifying this issue

Comment: This document says Google Workspaces changed their cookie policy on **January 2nd 2024**: https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2023/10/upcoming-changes-to-third-party-cookies-in-google-drive.html - [the document links to instructions for enabling downloads on third-party sites (such as yours) using _Drive and Docs Publishing Flows_](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2023/10/upcoming-changes-to-third-party-cookies-in-google-drive.html) instead - I don't know if it's compatible with `<audio><source>` though.

Comment: Google actually is blocking on a **new CORS policy**. See this recent SO post and discussion  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77803187/having-trouble-displaying-an-image-from-google-drive-in-html-using-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Having trouble displaying an image from Google Drive in HTML using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77803187/having-trouble-displaying-an-image-from-google-drive-in-html-using-javascript)

Comment: Thanks Dai, GetSet and Jay Patel for your responses

Probably issue on Google's end which started happening from January 11, 2024 as explained in the threads mentioned by you guys.

Bug being tracked here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/319531488?pli=1

Not sure if Google will fix this..

Comment: Anyways had to resolve this issue by couple of workarounds:

Comment: 1. use of <iframe> which opens up the audio in the same page
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/<ABCD>/preview" />

Comment: 2. Use a Button with Audio Image and clicking on the button opens up the audio in a new page
<div>
<a href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/<ABCD>/view?usp=sharing">
<img src="audio.png" style="width:35px;height:35px;"></a>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

I enabled Google Drive API by creating a project in Google API Console and created credentials for API Key.

I changed the URL pattern as follows in the audio tag

```
 <audio controls="controls"> 
    <source src="https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{FILE_ID}?alt=media&key={API_KEY}" 
            type="audio/mp3">
 </audio>
```

This no longer gives a 403 Forbidden error and works as expected.