# Customize google iFrame tag

Tags: image, iframe, google-drive-api, embed

I'm aware that we cannot any more display image with img tag since Jan 2 2023. So we tried to use the iframe tag, but we have a black background with the image in the center. We tried to use Css style but nothing changed. Also, there is no attribute in the iframe tag which can permit to take away this background. Finally, we searched in Google documentation but nothing. Is there any way to customize this iframe image integration?

Anyone can help please?

Comment: To help you get a more accurate answer, it would be beneficial if you could provide a minimal, reproducible example code that demonstrates the issue you're facing. This would allow the community to better understand your problem and provide targeted solutions. If you're unsure, please refer to [Stack Overflow Guide on Creating a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Including a reproducible example will greatly increase your chances of receiving a helpful response.

Comment: Thank you @SputnikDrunk2 the is a example code for what i want to do : 
`<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/{FILE_ID}/preview"></iframe>`
i want to customize the rendering

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77803819) work for you?